# Error while parsing xml with etree python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have `xml` which is having 6042 lines of data.

I am parsing it by following code ,

```
import urllib2
import lxml.etree as ET
print 'Started Execution here'
url="url goes here"
xmldata = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
root = ET.fromstring(xmldata)
print 'Done'
print root
for xin in root:
    print xin.tag, xin.attrib
```

Sometimes it runs successfully , but sometimes it shows following errors,

```
1. lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: ClinicID line 54 and location, line 54, column 60016

2. httplib.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(964 bytes read)
```

Clarification for 1st error : I have downloaded [XmlValidator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlvalidator/) and just copied my `xml` to this application. And it show no errors in it. It clearly shows that `xml` is totally error free.

Then whats wrong i am doing here ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my xml format

```
<locations>
    <location>
        <LocationID>A</LocationID>
        <ClinicID>111</ClinicID>
        <buildingType>A Type</buildingType>
        <address>Address</address>
        <address2>>Address 1</address2>
        <city>City 1</city>
        <state>State 1</state>
        <zip>Zip 1</zip>
    </location>
    <location>
        <LocationID>A</LocationID>
        <ClinicID>111</ClinicID>
        <buildingType>A Type</buildingType>
        <address>>Address</address>
        <address2>>Address</address2>
        <city>City 1</city>
        <state>State 1</state>
        <zip>Zip 1</zip>
    </location>
    .   
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <location>
        <LocationID>A</LocationID>
        <ClinicID>111</ClinicID>
        <buildingType>A Type</buildingType>
        <address>>Address</address>
        <address2>>Address</address2>
        <city>City 1</city>
        <state>State 1</state>
        <zip>Zip 1</zip>
    </location>


</locations>
```

**UPDATE**

I have downloaded xml file and tried to open it locally . It is working without any error. Then why sometime it is not working with urllib2.urlopen(url).read() ? Any limitations ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the XML. does it have a namespace?

Comment: How do you know the complete XML document is fetched? You need to account for this as you are relying on an external service.

Comment: try to print xmldata . Its not complete. try using `urllib2.urlopen(url).read(964)` in place of `urllib2.urlopen(url).read()`

Comment: @ChristophHa I don't know in which circumstances , it behaves randomly.

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149100/incompleteread-using-httplib

Comment: print `xmldata` in your script to verify that the XML fetched is correct/incorrect

Comment: @ChristophHa xml is having 6042 lines of data. Is this problem is caused due to large xml file ?

Comment: @ChristophHa I just downloaded xml file and tried to open it locally  . It is working without any error. Then why sometime it is not working with `urllib2.urlopen(url).read()` ? Any limitations ?

Comment: I think what is discussed here might be the same issue which you are facing 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273051/urlopen-errno-2-python